# Margin issue making a Visual Studio 2008 project with Crystal Reports.

Tags: visual-studio-2008, printing, crystal-reports

Ive made some really simple labels in Crystal Reports and they work great. Now when I made a very simple Visual Studio 2008 program that just launches these crystal reports the margins are slightly off. It adds a bottom and right margin of ~0.5cm, and some very small margins on the left and top, normally it wouldnt be such a big deal but its a 1 inch label so space is a hot commodity.

So now I have these labels all squished together with white space on the right and bottom. Is there a setting or something I am missing in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Is your report, page setup configuration linked to a specific printer?

I have found in the past, the easiest way to prevent these issues is to "disassociate".

Comment: Unfortunately the report is tied to the printer, it would be preferable for it to stay this way. When I write the report and launch it straight from Crystal Reports it works great but as soon as I launch it from my VS project the margins are mess up. But Ill try and not set a default printer just to see if thats the cause, thank you again for your help and quick answer.